# Desktop WPF Application with remote Web UI like utorrent

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I developed a windows desktop application using vb.net. I want to use the application with windows headless server. It will be easier if it has a web interface like utorrent.  My initial approach was to write the current state to a text file (JSON/XML) and then read the file from the web interface. but it leads to too much read/write operation. is their any better approach? how about using REST API calls?

Comment: Raise a condition when the file is changed? Or avoid XML stuff altogether and use COV (change of value) paradigm to update just what's changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a WCF web service from your WPF application, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application

That would expose an API that you could run a client against (eg. using Javascript on a web page).